# Issue in Maven project while running

Tags: html, eclipse, maven, tomcat7

First of all, I am newbie in maven.

My Maven project suddenly started giving me 4o4 error on browser when I am running it.

I created one maven project with maven archetype:webapp and started putting my stuff there, it was successful, but now something is wrong there.

In web.xml, I have mentioned welcome file as index.html

My directory structure as below:

[image]

The error which I am facing is below:

[image]

Can anyone help me, whats wrong here?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

it seems you renamed the context from "InterApp" to "interApp_Accounting_v1" - can you try to access the webapp using that new name?

So I would guess: http://localhost:8080/interApp_Accounting_v1/

The name is derived from the finalName inside the pom.xml:

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
```

see: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

It can be changed using the finalName in the pom or via the maven war plugin: 
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html

Otherwise you need to have a look in the log files if the war file could not be deployed.

Comment: No.. thats not the issue. its working on my other laptop. But donno whats the problem here...

Comment: well your first screenshot shows the target folder and the war file. If eclipse deploys that war file into tomcat and uses the same name then the url has to match. You might have changed the context root in the eclipse WTP server settings to /InterApp - if so you need to do that on other computers as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in web.xml, I gave url pattern like /* and if it matches then redirect to service class, thats why it was not able to render welcome page.